# How do I get images from database for Cross Slide image gallery?

Tags: php, javascript, database, phpmyadmin

I'm using [Crossslide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/) image gallery, and here is my image javascript file code which is connected to the index.php (which only has an ad_image div for the gallery)

```
$(function() {
$('#ad_image').crossSlide({                     
  sleep: 5,
  fade: 2
}, [
  { src: 'images/slideshow/1.jpg' },
  { src: 'images/slideshow/2.jpg' },
  { src: 'images/slideshow/3.jpg' }
])
});
```

I set up a database table screen_image in phpmyadmin, and would like to get images(eg 1.jpg, 2.jpg) from database rather than from the code above. The reason for doing so is that I am planning to build a backend/admin for it later on.

How do I go about connecting the Javascript file above to database using php? I'm new to this php/backend so a bit detailed explanation/coding would be very helpful.

Thank you for your help.

Regards
S:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is your image.php page

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("display");
?>

<html>
<head>
you can link all your javascript files here
<script type="text/javascript" src="you js file name with relative path"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="you js file name with relative path"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

this code will go like this in this script tag

```
    $(function() {
    $('#ad_image').crossSlide({                     
      sleep: 5,
      fade: 2
    }, [<?php

          $arr = array();
          $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `screen_image`');
          while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
          {
               $arr="{ src: 'images/slideshow/".$row['Your image field']."' }";
          }
           echo implode(',',$arr);
        ?>

    ])
    });
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php mysql_close($link); ?>
```

Comment: I thought he was storing the images in the db, but you might be right perhaps he meant the file names only.

Comment: hi Rahul, thanks for your reply, my datavase name is display and screen_images is a table under it. The code above is a javascript file, can i write php code in javascript directly? i tried the code, but my image field become blink, any suggestions? Thank you very much. S:)

Comment: No you cannot write php code directly in a javascript file but you can write javascript code in php file. So just write the above block of code in your php file

Comment: Thank you Rahul, Do i just put down
$(function() {
$('#ad_image').crossSlide({                     
  sleep: 5,
  fade: 2
}, [includes/images.php
])
}); and put your code in images.php? how does linking files in javascript files work, in another word how do I connect my javascript file to the php file? Sorry I'm new to this, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

replace the image links with a link to a script such as

```
  { src: 'scripts/image.php?image=1' },
  { src: 'scripts/image.php?image=2' },
  { src: 'scripts/image.php?image=3' }
```

the script would query the database and server the image.

image.php

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("testblob");
$id= (int) $_GET['image'];
$sql = "SELECT image FROM testblob WHERE image_id=$id";
$result = mysql_query("$sql");
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: Hi Dagon, thank you very much. Do I have to put image=1, 2, 3 in the javascript file? Also for the image.php, how does it know to connect to image table screen_image in the databse? Sorry I'm new to php, need some explanation. Thanks very much!

Comment: @SamlAm if your only storing the image file names in the db, then look at rahul's answer

Comment: Hi Dagon, thanks for your help. My end goal is to build an admin page to upload the images to the site, but at the mo i am trying to connect my front end to the database first. Sorry i'm confused about this data connection business as you can see I'm a front end developer trying to learn. I tried Rahul and your code but no luck. My database is called display, and screen_images is a table, can you write php in javascript file above like Rahul suggested? or shall i follow your suggestion? I really appreciate your help. thank you. S